# First cell of custom UITableViewCell is blank

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, xcode7

I am querying parse for some information and displaying the info in a UITableViewCell, there is only one entry in the table, a test entry with fictional information but the table is displaying the first cell blank and then the second cell with the information in the table. I have attempted to google this and also add more rows of testing info but either way the table displays one cell at the beginning with no info
Here is my code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "marathons")
    query.orderByAscending("end")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (marathons, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil ){
        //success

            for marathon in marathons! {
            self.Name.append(marathon["Name"] as! String)
            self.entryNumber.append(marathon["Number"] as! Int)
            self.totalEntries.append(marathon["entries"] as! Int)
            self.runnerDistance.append(marathon["distance"] as! Int)


            }
           self.TableView.reloadData()

        }else {
        print(error)

        }
    }



}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//MARK: TableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Name.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let singleCell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell


    singleCell.Name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.entryNumber.text = "\(entryNumbers[indexPath.row])"
    singleCell.totalEntries.text = "\(entires[indexPath.row])"
    singleCell.runnerDistance.text = "\(distance[indexPath.row])"



    return singleCell


}
```

Name, entryNumber, totalEntries, and runnerDistance defined as:

```
@IBOutlet var Name: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var entryNumber: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var totalEntries: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var runnerDistance: UILabel!
```

Any advice? I am using swift, parse as my back end, and XCODE 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are the model objects defined in your code? You're appending to objects named `Name`, `entryNumber`, `totalEntries`, and `runnerDistance`, but you're trying to assign values from properties named `entryNumbers` `entries` and `distance`.

Edit:
I see what's going on here. Based off your comment, you're initializing your arrays like this:
`var names = [String()]`
That actually creates an array with one empty string in it `[""]`. When you call `append`, you're adding another element to the array, which makes you wind up with `["","John"]`. if you want an empty array you should be creating it like this:
`var names = [String]()`

Comment: I have updated the original question with  var Name = [String()]
var entryNumber = [Int()]
var totalEntries = [Int()]
var runnerDistance = [Int()]

Comment: Okay so you have a variable named `Name` which is a string array, but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you're assigning the cell's field's text property to `names[indexPath.row]`. There's no property named `names` as far as I can tell.

Comment: oh I apologize I don't know what I was thinking I now wrote the correct information

Comment: IBOutlet var Name: UILabel!

IBOutlet var entryNumber: UILabel!

IBOutlet var totalEntries: UILabel!

IBOutlet var runnerDistance: UILabel!

Comment: thank you that worked would you happen to know why that made the difference?